# How can I modify text in Font-Awesome?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg">
    robfran@gmail.com
</i>
```

I have the following code. How can I change the font type of "example@gmail.com"?

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding here. Font Awesome provides only icons, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I created an icon of an envelope and then I displayed the email address. Now I want to change the font type of the email addres..is it possible?

Comment: Oh, got it now. In that case, CalvT's answer pretty much covers what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30490997/3334049

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want a font that is not Font-Awesome.

Do something like this:

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i><span class="email_font">example@gmail.com</span>
```

CSS

```
span.email_font {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif !important;
}
```

Where Times New Roman is the font that your email address is, and Georgia and Serif are backup fonts in case Times New Romans isn't loaded on the computer/browser/mobile

You can also specify `font-style:` (this can be normal, italic and oblique), `font-weight:` (this can be normal, bold or a number), and `font-size:` (number in px, or a % etc). There are others, but those are the basics.

So we could do

```
span.email_font {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif !important;
    font-style: italic !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

That would give you your email in Times New Roman, in italic, bold and the size of 15px. I have added the `!important` to make sure that these styles get implemented.

If you want to do it inline to simplify, thought this is not recommened.

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
<span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Georgia, Serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px ;">example@gmail.com</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

FontAwesome applies the glyph fonts using the css `::before` pseudo element.

The reason that when you change the font for the `.fa` selector the glyphs disappear is because the FontAwesome stylesheet applies the font to the `.fa` selector.

All you have to do is change the font using the `.fa` selector then reset the `.fa::before` selector back to FontAwesome.

```css
i.fa {
   font-family: mono;
}
i.fa::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg">robfran@gmail.com</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your text in a span with a class on it. Change the font on the class in your stylesheet. E.g.:

```
<html>
<head>
    .anotherFont 
    {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
</head>

<body>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
        <span class='anotherFont'>
            robfran@gmail.com
        <span>
</body>
</html>
```